# 3rd party keyboards (Swyft, SwiftKey, etc) do not work in iOS 8 GM

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, ios8

I'm running the GM build for iOS 8 on my iPhone 5s

My friend who has the identical setup, and has them working, so I don't know what my problem is.  I go through the same install process of these 3rd party keyboards, and I can install them and select them from the keyboard selection.

However, instead of the swift keyboard or the SwiftKey keyboard I see a large gray area where the keyboard should be.  No letters, nothing...i have to delete the keyboard to be able to type again.

Anyone else experiencing this?  I tried re-installing, rebooting phone, nothing seems to get them working...

I'm running the GM build for iOS 8...

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: True, it's a software question, which will result in some configuration changes and/or install operations. Does this not qualify for a valid question?

Comment: No, it's off topic since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though I missed a step.  If you don't "add full access" by tapping on the keyboard in settings and toggling the switch, they keyboard shows as a gray box but with no keys!!  You can't even close out of it without deleting the keyboard.

*EDIT nope, it's still broken. This option was only available for SwiftKey, and it only caused the keyboard to work for a brief moment, then it was back to grey box or not displaying a keyboard at all, as if I was connected to a hardware keyboard.

Still searching...